# What's the limit of spawning child_processes?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cloud-hosting

I have to serve a calculation via algorithm, I've been advised to use a child process per each opened socket, what I am about to do is something like that:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('node', ['algorithem.js']);
```

I know how to send argument to the algorithm process and how to receive results.

What I am concerned about, is how many socket (each socket will spawn a process) I can have?
How can I resolve this with my cloud hosting provider? so that my app gets auto scaled?

What's the recommended node js cloud hosting provider?

Finally, is this a good approach in using child processes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a fair approach when you have to do some heavy processing in node. However, starting a new process introduces some overhead, so be aware. The number of sockets (file descriptors) you can open is limited by your operating system. On Linux, the limits can seen using for example the [ulimit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html)-utility.

One alternative approach, that would remove the number of sockets/processes worry, is to run a separate algorithm/computation-server. This server could spawn N worker threads and would listen on a socket. When a computation request is received, this can for example be queued and processed by the first available thread. An advantage of this approach is that your computation server can run on any machine, freeing up resources for your node instance.

Comment: Actually, I am using node server just for this algorithm computation, but what do you mean by "This server could spawn N worker threads" ? isn't each spawn process is a thread on its own? or I have to create the threads by my self? can you please write a simple example to make it more clear? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I meant the other server process. Each spawned process is a separate process, but spawn() uses the popen-system call to provide communication. Node is single-threaded, so thus, it cannot create normal threads. The motivation behind my example was to provide an alternate approach where you could reduce the number of open sockets.

Comment: Can you please explain how can I reduce number of opened sockets? can one socket serve more than one connection?

Comment: Yes. The node instance that forwards the requests to the process that performs the algorithm could add an identifier to each request. When the reply arrives, you could match this ID and send the reply back to the correct client. That way, you would multiplex multiple requests onto one socket.

Comment: Unfortunately not, none that are easy to share. But for the nodejs-part, you could for example look at the ClientRequest's connect-event example in the docs: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connect_1. It should be easy to adapt to other protocols than HTTP. You could for example insert an id before the original request.

Comment: Isn't multiplexing requests idea is what socket.io multiplexing all about? https://npmjs.org/package/socket.io-parser ? if so, then I can get my app powered with socket.io ? if not, do you know a node module that would implement multiplexing multiple requests?